# How to prove this recurrence with generating functions

Tags: generating-functions, stirling-numbers

I'm studying generating functions.
I'm trying to understand exercise 6.7 in this article:
https://www.gameludere.it/2019/05/19/funzioni-generatrici-esponenziali-e-applicazioni/#1_Le_funzioni_generatrici_esponenziali

But there is a step I don't understand.

That is, he has this generating function:
$$G_{r}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n \brace r} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
and use $G_{r}(x)=G_{1}(x)\cdot G_{r-1}(x)$ to prove that
$$G_{r}(x) = \frac{(e^x-1)^r}{r!}$$

How does he know that $G_{r}(x)=G_{1}(x)\cdot G_{r-1}(x)$?

I've tried to do second member manipulation, but I don't find any simple method to verify the identity.
I suppose there is some smart trick to apply.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is known that $$ \frac{(e^x-1)^r}{r!} = \sum_{n=r}^\infty {n \brace r}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \brace r}\frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

For you, this means that $$G_r(x)=rG_1(x)G_{r-1}(x).$$

Comment: This identity is just what is asked to prove in the exercise 6.7 I mention.
Not possible to use to prove the recurrence.